# Selecting a specific tab on page load with the jQuery plugin "Acid Tabs"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First let me say I am quite new to javascript, so I am sorry if this is an easy question. I am using the jQuery plugin "Acid Tabs" found [here](http://www.my-html-codes.com/jquery-tabs-my-first-plugin) to handle the tabs on my webpage. So far I have been able to do everything I want, except get a tab other the #1 to display at page load.

As far as I can tell the plugin does not provide a simple way to do this, and I can not find an answer on here that seems to work. I had thought that I could provide a simulated click on one of the other tabs with the following code inserted into the page:

```
$('#tabHeader_2').click ();
```

But after trying many variations on this I could not find a way to make it work. I hope I am missing something obvious here, is there any way to make it work?